# Speech to text match with specific word ionic v3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, speech-recognition

I'm creating an App using Ionic 3.4.0 and angular. I've already install ionic-native/speech-recognition.
I can change background color by saying the name with speech recognition.
Example if I want to make the backgroudn black i say black, if i want it green i say green.

But what i want now its display the name by saying a diffent word. 
Example: If a say "Hello" the background comes black and if I say "Goodbye" background comes green.

```js
start() {

        this.speechRecognition.startListening()
          .subscribe(
            (matches: Array<string>) => {
              this.bgcolor = matches[0];
            },
            (onerror) => console.log('error:', onerror)
          )

  }
```

```html
<ion-content padding [style.background-color]="bgcolor">
 <div style="text-align: center;">
 <img style="width: 100%;" src="assets/img/entradakiotron.gif">
 
</div>

 <ion-card style="background: #1d1d1d;">
  <ion-card-header style="color: #fff;">
    KIOTRON:
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content style="color: #fff;">
    Hola ¿en qué te puedo ayudar?
  </ion-card-content>

  <ion-card-content style="color: #fff;">

    {{ bgcolor }} 
    
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
  
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Did you solve this?